# ActivityGroup and ActionBar of the child activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am supporting some pretty nasty legacy Android code that uses ActivityGroup. I added an ActionBar to the ActivityGroup, and I need it to overlay all of the content, using FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY. But thing is that it overlays only the content that is attached directly to the ActivityGroup, not the child activities in the group, so every time I show the action bar part of the content moves down (child activities are transparent, don't ask why).

Setting styles to the child Activities doesn't help at all, their getActionBar() returns null even after requesting FEATURE_ACTION_BAR, so needless to say that requesting FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY doesn't do any good either. Rewriting the application to use Fragments or not use any groups at all is too much effort, so that would be last resort. Is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I ran to the same issue, and for me the problem was that I assigned

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

At the `<application>` level. I moved it to the specific activity that I wanted to remove the action bar from it, and it solved the issue.